# Can a complex layout be classed so it can be used repeatedly in layout?

Tags: python, kivymd

I have a specific Boxlayout that contains labels to show values in a row; now there are several rows and each is in a boxlayout. I was wondering if I could make a class of the boxlayout including  all the labels. So when I go to my .kv file I just call the class and don't have to repeat all the params.
EDIT: IHAVE PLACED THE CORRESPONDING .KV

```py
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: "My Stock Tickers"
        
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
        type: 'top'

    MyBox:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 400, 100
        
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        #elevation: 20
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        
        md_bg_color: [0, .7, 1, 1]

        #Widget:
            #size_hint_y : None
            #height: 10

        MDLabel:
            text: "Enter Ticker"
            font_size: 15
            halign: "center"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            

        MDTextFieldRound:
            #id: user
            width: 30
            font_size: 18
            #padding_y: 15
            spacing: '20dp'

        MDFIconButton:
            user_font_size: "15sp"
            icon: "plus"
            opposite_colors: True
            elevation: 8
            md_bg_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            spacing: '20dp'


        MDLabel:
            id: t_price
            text: "000.00"
            font_size: 15
            halign: "center"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 10

        MDLabel:
            id: t_change
            text: "00.00"
            font_size: 15
            halign: "center"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 10

    MyBox:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 400, 200
        md_bg_color: [0, .9, 1, 1]
        #spacing: 10
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        


        MyBox:                                   # Title Row
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: 30

            Widget:
                size_hint_x : None
                width: 20
            MDLabel:
                #color: 72/255,89/255,89/255,1
                color: 0,0,0,1
                text: "NAME"
                
                halign: 'left'
                size_hint: None, 1
                width: 100
                

            MDLabel:
                color: (0,0,0,1)
                text: "Value"

            MDLabel:
                color: (0,0,0,1)
                text: "Change"

            MDLabel:
                color: (0,0,0,1)
                text: "Chg %"



        MyRowBox:                                                  #1st Row
            id: row1
            #self.name.text: "Dow"         ????????
            #self.value.text: "000.000"    ????????
            #self.change.text: "000.000"   ????????
            #self.percnt.text: "0.01%"     ????????
```

My example of what i thought would work would be something like this (in python): EDIT: I PLACED A WORKING SAMPLE

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RectangularElevationBehavior
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.widget import MDWidget

class MDFIconButton(MDIconButton):
    pass

class MyBox(MDBoxLayout):
    class update():
        pass

class MyRowBox(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRowBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        size_hint= 1, None
        height= 30
        self.add_widget(MDWidget(size_hint_x= None, width= 20))
        self.name = (MDLabel( color= [72 / 255, 89 / 255, 89 / 255, 1],halign= 'left', size_hint=[None, 1],width= 100))
        self.add_widget(self.name)
        self.value = MDLabel(halign= 'left')
        self.add_widget(self.value)
        self.change = MDLabel(halign='left')
        self.add_widget(self.change)
        self.percnt = MDLabel(halign='left')
        self.add_widget(self.percnt)

        self.name.text = "Dow"
        self.value.text = "000.000"
        self.change.text = "000.000"
        self.percnt.text = "000.000"
        self.change.font_size = 12
        self.percnt.font_size = 12
        self.name.color = [72 / 255, 89 / 255, 89 / 255, 1]
        self.value.color = [0, 0, 0, 1]
        self.change.color = [0, 0, 0, 1]
        self.percnt.color = [0, 0, 0, 1]
        print(self)

class MyTextField(MDTextField):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_file('MyStocks.kv')


MainApp().run()
```

> As it is it does not work. is this something that could be made to work or am I being too optimistic. I will also be needing to set Id's for all the labels.

EDIT: The situation is that I do not know how to update the values. In the python file the labels have `names` which I can address fom the python file (as you can see from the demo). Now, when the class is instantiated in the .kv file the complete layout gets and `id`. The question is how do I change the values of the labels using the `id` of the layout and the `names` of the labels. Bear in mind the layout will be instantiated multiple times.

I thank you in advance for any assistance on this. Thanks, Ray.

Comment: It seems you are looking for [**`dynamic classes`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes).

Comment: Ok, I guess I was unto something. I'll read up on Dynamic classes. I was also thinking on listviews. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I was not too far off. My concern now is how to address the id's. I have 4, but how would I address them in the .kv file: `self.ids.name` doesn't work

Comment: You should consider posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I have placed updated code, which works and displays the situation. Thanks again ApuCuder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your issues properly, you just need a dynamic class. With dynamic class you can create an object with or without some propertie(s) that can be used with little to no further modifications. In `kvlang` it is even easier to build and modify the class (afterwards).

First create a dynamic class with some deterministic (here, predetermined or fixed no. of) properties in python as,

```py
class MyRowBox(MDBoxLayout):
    name = StringProperty("NAME")
    value = StringProperty("Value")
    change = StringProperty("Change")
    percnt = StringProperty("Chg %")
```

Then design it in `kvlang` as,

```py
<MyRowBox>:
    md_bg_color: [0.5, .7, 0.2, 1]
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "30dp"

    Widget:
        size_hint_x : None
        width: "20dp"

    MDLabel:
        color: 72/255,89/255,89/255,1
        color: 0,0,0,1
        text: root.name
        halign: 'left'
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: "100dp"

    MDLabel:
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        text: root.value

    MDLabel:
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        text: root.change

    MDLabel:
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        text: root.percnt
```

Thus your modified code in `.kv` file should now look like,

```py
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: "My Stock Tickers"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
        type: 'top'

    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "400dp", "100dp"

        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        #elevation: 20
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25

        md_bg_color: [0, .7, 1, 1]

        #Widget:
            #size_hint_y : None
            #height: 10

        MDLabel:
            text: "Enter Ticker"
            font_size: 15
            halign: "center"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]


        MDTextFieldRound:
            #id: user
            width: 30
            font_size: 18
            #padding_y: 15
            spacing: '20dp'

        MDFIconButton:
            user_font_size: "15sp"
            icon: "plus"
            opposite_colors: True
            elevation: 8
            md_bg_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            spacing: '20dp'


        MDLabel:
            id: t_price
            text: "000.00"
            font_size: 15
            halign: "center"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 10

        MDLabel:
            id: t_change
            text: "00.00"
            font_size: 15
            halign: "center"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 10

    MyRowBox:    # Same class as a title row
                 # due to its initilization style.
                 # Change it if you need to.
    
    MyRowBox:
        id: row1
        name: "Dow"
        value: "000.000"
        change: "000.000"
        percnt: "0.01%"

    MyRowBox:
        id: row2
        name: "Dow"
        value: "000.000"
        change: "000.000"
        percnt: "0.01%"

    MyRowBox:
        id: row3
        name: "Dow"
        value: "000.000"
        change: "000.000"
        percnt: "0.01%"

    MyRowBox:
        id: row4
        name: "Dow"
        value: "000.000"
        change: "000.000"
        percnt: "0.01%"



<MyRowBox>:
    md_bg_color: [0.5, .7, 0.2, 1]
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "30dp"

    Widget:
        size_hint_x : None
        width: "20dp"

    MDLabel:
        color: 72/255,89/255,89/255,1
        color: 0,0,0,1
        text: root.name
        halign: 'left'
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: "100dp"

    MDLabel:
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        text: root.value

    MDLabel:
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        text: root.change

    MDLabel:
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        text: root.percnt
```

### Update (usage case):

The usage case of this class in python could be like,

```py
# Please add the rest / necessary blocks.

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return self.root


    def on_start(self):
        box1 = self.root.ids.row1
        box2 = self.root.ids.row2
        # etc.
        for i, box in enumerate([box1, box2, ]):
            box.name = str(i+1)
            box.value = str(100+i)
            box.change = str(i)
            box.percnt = f"{i/100:0.2%}"


MainApp().run()
```

---

### Note:

1. I used [`dp`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html#dimensions) for better consistency. You may change it.
2. You perhaps need the class `MyBox` no more.

Comment: That is very good code ApuCoder, and it generates 2 questions: where do place the first KV code, in a separate .kv file, or together in the .kv file or in the python file? And, what does the code look like to, for instance, fill in the text for, id: row3 value?

Comment: Following this pattern it doesn't matter where you define it, just make sure that it's available to the main program. I can't follow your second query.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I have to fill all of those labels with text. For each row there are 4 labels. So I'll need a line of code that would be something like: `root.ids.row3['Value'].text = "4,455.67"`. How is that line exactly.

Comment: To set a value in python you can do as you do for a normal property, like : `source_instance.ids.row3.value = some_value_as_string`.

Comment: and `source_instance` would be? I'm sorry to be such a pest, but I have no clue... I've tried `app`, `root`, `MyRowBox`....nothing like that works. I'm using just the code you sent, so you know.

Comment: I've updated with an example.

Comment: I think that is the answer I was waiting for. I will try it and let you know. Thanks ApuCoder

Comment: ApuCoder, that is it. That is what I was after. I have learnt a lot in what may seem a simple example of coding. So to summarize: the dynamic class can contain widgets but also variables, which are local to each instance of the class. Then another thing is the `on_start` is a method which (auto)runs after the ids dict is created so it allows for the access (assignment of values) to the id's on `start`. Thank you immensely.

Comment: `on_start` is actually a default method for [`App`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App) class.